# iterate through form elements in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, loops

I am trying to iterate through all form elements with id that begins with a specified prefix and create an xml string with results, but it is getting a bit complicated as forms form input types seem to have different behaviors . Does this functionality already javascript,  jQuery or third party jQuery module?

```
 function fnPreIterate(){                
         var XMLstring;
         $(':input[id*="f1"]').each(function() {             
            XMLstring += (" <" +this.name+ '>' + this.value + "</"  + this.name + "> " );       
        });         
        $('#XMLstring').html("<pre>" + fnEncodeEntities(string) + "</pre>");
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use:

```
$(this).val()
```

instead of

```
this.value
```

you'll save a lot of headaches with difference in form elements.

Another way to iterate is to use `.serializeArray()`:

```
$.each($('#form').serializeArray(), function() {             
            string += (" <" +this.name+ '>' + this.value + "</"  + this.name + "> " );      
        });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: To select by prefix, you should do `$(':input[id^="f1"]')` (use ^ instead of *)

Comment: You shouldn't use `something.each()` if `something` is not a jQuery object. Use `$.each(something, function(idx, obj) { ... })` instead. Besides that, the callback is pretty incorrect since you are't iterating over DOM objects anymore.

Comment: You're totally right, I don't know what I was thinking. I've updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).val()` to get the value.

Additionally you mixed up `XMLString` and `string` which results in your code creating a global variable and failing when it's called a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you should try:

```
function fnPreIterate(){                
  var XMLstring='';
  $(':input[id^="f1"]').each(function() {             
    var e = $(this), name=e.attr('name'), val=e.val();
    XMLstring += (" <" +name+ '>' + val + "</"  + name + "> " );      
  });         
  $('#XMLstring').html("<pre>" + fnEncodeEntities(XMLstring) + "</pre>");
};
```

I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of jQuery's [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing?
try using $(this) selector in your function instead. something like this
$(this).attr('name') and $(this).val()